# R markdown ! Package amsmath Error: \hat allowed only in math mode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, rmarkdown

Here is the error I'm getting trying to knit my R markdown file.

```
output file: HW4.knit.md

! Package amsmath Error: \hat allowed only in math mode.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile HW4.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See HW4.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I've been struggling with this for like 30 minutes, when I scan through my code it appears that every instance of $\hat$ is in math mode, so I'm extremely confused.

Here is every instance in my document of \hat :

```
$\hat{\beta_0}= 15.0352$
$\hat{\beta_1} = -0.5802$
$\hat{\beta_0}$
$\hat{\beta_0}$
$\hat{\beta_0} = 15.0352$
$$\hat{y} \pm t_{0.92}\cdot SE$$
$$\hat{y} \pm t_{0.92}\cdot SE$$
$\hat{\beta_1}=\sum X_iY_i/\sum X_1^2$
$L(\hat{\beta_1})> L(18)$
$\hat{\beta_1} = 17.9285$
$\hat{\beta_1}$
```

I would appreciate any help, let me know if you need further information.
I'm not putting the full document here because it's about 10 pages long.

Comment: What you showed does not produce any error is a empty document,  so....what do you expect us to tell you? Remove the pages 6-10 of your 10 pages document and test if the issue is still there. If not, recover the original and remove pages 1-5, retaining only the half part containing the error. Check  that the error type is still the same, not a new one. Repeat the process to further reduce the document two 2 pages,  1 page, ... and  so on  until have a single sentence or formula. Then the error will be evident. Otherwise,  post that reduced versión.

Comment: @Fran Thanks for the advice, I'll try that. This has been driving me crazy

Comment: It's possible that a `$` was accidentally omitted from the previous math string.  The log file should give a kine number,  Back up from there and look for that sort of omission.

Comment: If you have access to the intermediate HW4.tex file, you can run it through pdflatex and see which line is the culprit.

Comment: The HW4.tex by default  will be removed  after the PDF compilation in Rstudio but is possible see it with  `keep_tex: yes` in the YAML header. Alternatively, you can also export the markdown  to latex directly with `pandoc`.